# Use of unassigned local variable in out parameter

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with C# giving the "Use of unassigned local variable" compile error. What am I missing?

```cs
// returns generic result of a function with error message 
// why the function failed
public class Result
{
    public bool isSuccess = true;
    public string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    public static implicit operator bool(Result r)
    {
        return r.isSuccess;
    }

    public static Result operator &(Result a, Result b)
    {
        return !a.isSuccess ? a : b;
    }

    public static Result operator |(Result a, Result b)
    {
        if (a.isSuccess)
        {
            return a;
        }
        if (b.isSuccess)
        {
            return b;
        }
        return new Result
        {
            isSuccess = false,
            errorMessage = $"{a.errorMessage}\nOut{b.errorMessage}"
        };
    }

    public static bool operator false(Result a)
    {
        return !a.isSuccess;
    }

    public static bool operator true(Result a)
    {
        return a.isSuccess;
    }
}

static Result Func1(int nIn, out int nOut)
{
    nOut = nIn + 1;
    return new Result();
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var resultA =
        Func1(0, out var a1) &&
        Func1(a1, out var a2); // compiles fine

    var resultB =
        Func1(0, out var b1) &&
        Func1(b1, out var b2) &&
        Func1(b2, out var b3); // Use of unassigned local variable 'b2'
}
```

Comment: One option would be to use & instead of &&. That will not use short-circuiting, so every partial expression will be executed and so every output parameter will be assigned. That would not be appropriate in all situations but if there are no side-effects then it should be fine.

Comment: yeah but the idea is for function to fail and not execute any further logic as soon as the first call fails. If I use &, then everything will be evaluated prior to evaluating the final result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this *may* be a bug in the compiler - I'd personally expect `b2` to be definitely assigned there. The spec for definite assignment is pretty hairy though, so I'm not going to try to prove it one way or another right now. It's possible that the rules aren't "clever" enough to work out that the only way that `(x && y)` is true is if both `x` and `y` are evaluated, and so in `(x && y) && z`, `z` should be able to rely on both `x` and `y` having been evaluated.

However, it's fairly easy to work around, just with an extra pair of parentheses:

```cs
var resultB =
        Func1(0, out var b1) &&
        (Func1(b1, out var b2) && Func1(b2, out var b3));
```

Comment: This works as expected with `static bool Func1(int nIn, out int nOut)` though, so it must be about the implicit operators.

Comment: @GSerg yeah this was my older pattern and it worked perfectly

Comment: the problem is that this is only a simple example. I have functions that do many more things 
`           var result1 =
                Func1(0, out var b1) &&
                Func1(b1, out var b2) &&
                Func1(b2, out var b3) &&
                Func1(b3, out var b4) &&
                Func1(b4, out var b5) &&
                etc`

Comment: This also works: `var resultB = (bool)Func1(0, out var b1) && Func1(b1, out var b2) && Func1(b2, out var b3);`. The removal of the `public static Result operator &` also fixes it.

Comment: @GSerg while this would work in this context, `resultB` would now be a bool and not Result. I have many functions of kind `Result DoABunchOfStuff() { return DoThingA(out resultA) && DoThingB(resultA, out resultB) && DoThingC(resultB, out resultC) & etc`

Comment: @Chebz: While it's possible that it *should* work, you're into corner case territory between out parameters, custom operators and definite assignment across multiple expressions. You may want to look for an alternative approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you remove the `bool operator false` it complains that one must exist for the `operator&` to short circuit, and indeed in the presence of `bool operator false` it does. The rules of short circuiting are well defined, so the compiler knows that either the first two expressions will be evaluated, or it won't need to evaluate the third one - and indeed, this is what happens with primitive types. I speculate that here the compiler is trying to account for `operator&` lying about its result, but I can't see how it could lie such that evaluation proceeds without calling both functions.

Comment: @GSerg: Indeed. That's why I think it's *either* a subtle compiler bug, *or* the spec doesn't try to handle this combination of features. I definitely agree that *logically* it should work.

Comment: only thing I can think of is defining parameters ahead of time like 
`int b1 = default;
int b2 = default;
int b3 = default;
var resultB =
        Func1(0, out b1) &&
        Func1(b1, out b2) &&
        Func1(b2, out b3);`
not sure if this is safe?

Comment: @Chebz: Yes, that should be safe. You could even declare them all in one statement: `int b1 = default, b2 = default, b3 = default;`